# Route 53 Setup for Elastic Beanstalk Blue/Green Deployment

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53, blue-green-deployment

I've setup the infrastructure to do an environment variable swap for blue/green deployment, but the way we have our Route 53 setup it isn't working.

Currently, we have the root A record pointing at the EBS Load Balancer, is this correct? I think it should be pointing directly to the EBS, but I don't know enough to know for sure. I didn't set it up, and I'm not sure why this configuration was selected.

Is my assumption correct, or is there a better way to set this up?

Any articles or answers would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following for a blue/green deployment. From Route 53:

1. Click "Create record"
2. Select "Simple routing"
3. Click "Define simple record"
4. Leave the subdomain blank for the root record
5. Choose "A record - Routes traffic to an IP4 address and some AWS resources"
6. Under Value/Route traffic to select "Alias to Elastic Beanstalk environment"
7. Choose your region
8. Select the environment you wish the record to point to.
9. Click "Define simple record"

You can then create a new A record with a subdomain to point to the environment you would like to do the blue-green deploy with. Then in the Elastic Beanstalk console:

1. Select one of the environments
2. Click Actions
3. Select "Swap environment URLs"
4. Select the environment for you would like to switch URLs